# How to determine the number of switches in bang-bang optimal control?

Tags: optimization, control-theory, optimal-control

I have a linear control problem, which suggests that the optimal control is of the bang-bang form.

- If $t_f$ is fixed and we want to make the cost as high as possible, how could we determine the number of bang-bang switches?
- Is it possible to give some analysis if, instead of fixing $t_f$, we add a penalty term $\alpha T$ to the cost function?

Comment: Bang-bang control is usually for minimal time optimal control with input constraints. But your problem is not minimal time, since the final time is already given and you also did not mention if there are input constraints. I do assume that the final state is given?

Comment: the input state is given. However the cost function is given as the fidelity between the standard "final state" and the real final state. I want the fidelity as high as possible.

Comment: So in the limit you want that the real final state is equal to a desired final state?

Comment: 1) I'd say that here we have the problem with the terminal cost $\Phi(x(t_f))$ (=fidelity) and a free right end (i.e. x(t_f) is not fixed). I do not think though that it is possible to estimate the number of switches. 2) You can easily add the penalty by maximizing $J=-\int_0^T \alpha dt + \Phi(x(T))$. However, I'm not sure if this will make the problem simpler.

Comment: Yes, in the limit I want that the real final state is equal to a desired final state.

Comment: @SiruiLu Then the solution will not be bang-bang, but something like [PMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pontryagin%27s_maximum_principle) instead.